# Xamarin doesn't remove a page from the stack

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to remove a page from the Xamarin Forms stack of pages using a decoupled model where I hook up to the PageService class inherited from a IPageService interface from my View Model but unfortunatly the page doesn't get removed.

I can't figure out why this method doesn't remove the required page from the stack. It behaves as if nothing has happened. When I debug it the stack count stays the same before and after the RemovePage method execution.

```
    public void RemovePageFromStack(int position)
    {
        var navigation = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;
        var navStack = navigation.NavigationStack;
        var stackCount = navStack.Count();
        navigation.RemovePage(navStack[stackCount - position]);
     }
```

Has anyone seen this work? Thanks.

Comment: instead of `navigation.RemovePage(navStack[stackCount - position]);` try saving the page as a variable first `var page = navStack[stackCount - position];` and then step through to make sure it's not null when you do `navigation.RemovePage(page);`.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but if you write it like this it works.

```
    public void RemovePageFromStack(int position)
    {
        var navigation = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;
        var navStack = navigation.NavigationStack;           
        var stackCount = navStack.Count();
        var page = navStack[stackCount - position];
        navigation.RemovePage(page);
    }
```